# ¿Como puedo repetir cada letra de u string?

Tags: javascript, string, funciones

Hola buenas estoy haciendo un ejercicio en el cual tengo que repetir cada letra de un string. Por ejemplo 'hola' deberia de devolver 'hhoollaa'

```js
function repetirCaracteres() {
  // Escribi una funcion llamada 'repeatCharacters' en el prototypo del objeto global String
  // que reciba como parametro un string
  // y devuelve un string en donde cada letra se repita una vez.
  // Por ej:
  // 'hola'.repeatCharacters() devuelve "hhoollaa"

  // Tu código aca:
  String.prototype.repeat = function repeatCharacters(word){
    const letters = word.split('')
    const repeated = letters.map(letter => letter.repeat(2))
    return repeated.join('')
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Por un lado debes poner el código fuera de la función `repetirCaracteres` porque no se ejecutará hasta que no la llames.

Además el string no se pasa como parámetro, sino como `this`.

`string` ya tiene una función [`repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat). Así que también deberías usar otro nombre si no quieres sobreescribirla. Si lo dejaras te encontrarías con una función recursiva infinita.

```js
String.prototype.repeatWord = function repeatCharacters(){
    const letters = this.split('')
    const repeated = letters.map(letter => letter.repeat(2))
    return repeated.join('')
}

console.log("hola".repeatWord())
```

Comment: El problema que tengo que escribir el codigo dentro la funcion ya definida, en este caso es repetirCaracteres.

Comment: Bueno. Puedes escribirlo ahí y luego llamas la función para que se hagan los cambios en el prototipo. También puede ser que el ejercicio esté mal planteado.

Comment: No pude dar con la solucion, pero seguire intentando. muchas gracias

Comment: de todas formas todavia el error me devuelve que repeatCharacters no es una funcion.

Comment: En el código de la respuesta lo escribí como `repeatWord` pero puedes cambiarle el nombre a la función. Sino obtendrás un error como ese.

Comment: Si lo pude solucionar, tenia que cambiar repeatWord y agregar 'repeatCharacters'

Answer (score 0):

Si es un ejercicio tal vez así saques mejor nota, aunque tendrías que sacarlo tu mismo.

Te dejo un ejemplo que tal vez te resulte más familiar que el del compañero pues usarás cosas que seguro estás aprendiendo a pillar soltura.

Te he añadido un parámetro en la funciín para que le puedas poner las veces que quieres que se repita la cadena

```js
function repetirCadena(str, veces){
  var nuevaCadena = "";
  
  for(var i=0; i<str.length; i++){
      for(var x=0; x<veces; x++){
          nuevaCadena += str.charAt(i);
      }
  }
  console.log(nuevaCadena);
}

repetirCadena("hola", 2);
repetirCadena("hola", 5);
```